# i am sending an email from SPD to muliple recipients, want to make sure all recipients has been received the mail.

Tags: designer-workflow

Through SPD Workflow I would like to send mail to 250 recipients in a single shot. Consider all recipients are valid. Incase workflow failed/crashed in the halfway, what will happen? it will rollback? or mail will be received by part of the recipients?. If part of the recipients received the mail, how to track those failed recipients?

To send an mail, I am following the below steps...

1.Action -> Send an Mail 
2. To -> Workflow Look up (look up column is an "People and Group" which accepts multiple values)

I request someone to help on this. OR suggest me the best alternative to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Send Email to SharePoint Group check this below link it helps..

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mahuja/archive/2008/04/01/resolving-workflow-status-stopped-when-sending-mail-to-a-sharepoint-group.aspx

http://www.mstechblogs.com/sharepoint/en/sharepoint-designer-workflow-does-not-send-email-to-groups/